# Why is Mongodb stuck in RECOVERING?

Tags: mongodb

I did a small change with rs.reconfig which caused my primary node being stuck in RECOVERING state. How can I correct this?

I just changed protocolVersion: Long("0") from protocolVersion: Long("1") with the following command:

```
rs.reconfig({
    _id: 'x',
    version: 803461,
    protocolVersion: Long("0"),
    members: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        host: '10.x.0.x:27017',
        arbiterOnly: false,
        buildIndexes: true,
        hidden: false,
        priority: 1,
        tags: {},
        slaveDelay: Long("0"),
        votes: 1
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        host: '10.x.0.x:27017',
        arbiterOnly: false,
        buildIndexes: true,
        hidden: false,
        priority: 1,
        tags: {},
        slaveDelay: Long("0"),
        votes: 1
      }
    ],
    settings: {
      chainingAllowed: true,
      heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000,
      heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10,
      electionTimeoutMillis: 10000,
      catchUpTimeoutMillis: 60000,
      getLastErrorModes: {},
      getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 },
      replicaSetId: ObjectId("5a884c37b6ccb139231011c9")
    }
  })
```

The node which was previously primary one

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: '10.x.0.x:27017',
  health: 1,
  state: 3,
  stateStr: 'RECOVERING',
  uptime: 804,
  optime: [Object],
  optimeDate: 2021-12-24T16:39:05.000Z,
  infoMessage: 'could not find member to sync from',
  configVersion: 803465,
  self: true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only protocol version 1 is supported in MongoDB 4.0+.

If you have manually configured an unsupported version, you can change it back using rs.reconfig with the `force:true` option